# Getting max value in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to sum a total where the year is less than the max year.

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!YEAR.value < max(Fields!YEAR.value), Fields!Year_Sold.Value,0))
```

it runs but i am getting #ERROR is my syntax correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by replacing the 0 with Nothing so here is what worked for me `=Sum(iif(Fields!YEAR.Value < Parameters!EndYear.Value, Fields!Year_Sold.Value, Nothing))`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the dataset for the **MAX** - aggregate functions require the dataset so they get the max over the whole dataset and not the one record.

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!YEAR.value < MAX(Fields!YEAR.value, "Dataset1"), Fields!Year_Sold.Value, 0))
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I'm still getting the #ERROR.

Comment: Are you using BIDS (Visual Studio shell)? If so, are you getting any warnings in the Error List or the Output window?

Comment: I'm using report builder 3.o.

Comment: What is the data type of **Year Sold**? I was assuming **INTEGER**. If it's a decimal , try using **CDEC(0)** instead of **0**. On another note, is that the right column - you're adding up your **Year_Sold** field?

Comment: Year_sold represent the number of items sold. and it is an integer

Comment: Does **SUM(Year_Sold)** work? If so, the issue is in the **YEAR**. I would make a table with your **YEAR** and **Year_Sold** fields and look for any bad data (export to Excel if it has a lot of records). It sounds like one of them has some non-numeric data. NULLS should be ignored with SUM though.....

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm using parameters so i tried to adjust my code to this `=Sum(IIF(Fields!YEAR.value < MAX(Parameters!EndYear.value,"STYLE"), Fields!Year_Sold.Value, 0))`

Comment: still getting the #ERROR though

Comment: The parameter wouldn't use the dataset - just `MAX(Parameters!EndYear.value) `.